# Why does assert appends a default assertion message

Tags: java, assert, assertions

While using asserts for e.g

```
try{ 
 assert email!=null : "Email is required"
} catch (AssertionError ae) {
 System.out.println(ae.getMessage());
}
```

above prints **Email is required. Expression: email!=null**

I don't want this extra message **Expression: email!=null** I know I can substring but thats a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mis-using `assert` here. It is not for controlling the flow of your program. You should use an `if` here.

You should only use [`assert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) when you are sure that the condition can not occur. In that case the application should crash and print what went wrong. Be aware that asserts maybe turned off when your application is started.

Comment: I will be using them in rest services to respond with proper error messages to user. It's a lot better then adding if-else for each parameter

Comment: @Hussain: If you really want to learn here something, it is to not use asserts in that way. if-else is absolutely fine.

Comment: +1 When you have a situation which can only mean you have a coding issue or a bug, use an assertion. It should be something you can safely turn off in production after reasonable testing.  If you are validating input or any "normal" error state, use an if/throw.

Comment: Indeed. Never use `assert` for input validation. For input validation you can consider using [Guava's preconditions](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) or [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way. Keep in mind that `assert` is generally something that should never occur during proper program operation. As such, the associated message is only for debugging.

From the the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html):

> Note that the detail message is *not* a user-level error message, so it is generally unnecessary to make these messages understandable in isolation, or to internationalize them. The detail message is meant to be interpreted in the context of a full stack trace, in conjunction with the source code containing the failed assertion.